# Run AppleScript on lid close?

Tags: macbook-pro, applescript, macos

I'm using a MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid-2014) running OS X El Capitan and I'm curious if I can run a script when I close my computer (without installing anything).

Note: I don't want to install anything.

Comment: I looked at that before; it requires that I install something.

Comment: No, the `ioreg -r -k AppleClamshellState | grep...` [solution by M K](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104560/93229) doesn't require any installation.

Comment: Want to make sure: I'll have to run that continuously; will that drain my battery?

Comment: Depends on the script/task. You probably want to [disable clamshell mode](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152777/how-to-disable-clamshell-mode-in-yosemite).