# screen lock using a script

Tags: screensaver

Is it possible to lock the screen in OS Yosemite using code? And then put in a scheduler to run every two minutes?

If so what script language are we talking, task scheduler program etc

Comment: Do you want to lock the screen every two minutes? What if a user is actively using the Mac? You could [Fast User Switch after two minutes of inactivity](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011-03-18-fast-user-switch-to-the-login-window-after-inactivity/).

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/80058/38539

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I would try completing this task:

1. Create a script file that will be executed every time the system starts:

> ```
> sudo nano ~/sleep.sh
> ```

2. Input the following text in the file:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> sleep 120
> pmset sleepnow
> #osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to sleep'
> ```

*Note: The last line with the # at the front is a substitute of the one above (pmset sleepnow)*

3. Open the CronJob editor in order to start the script frequently:

> env EDITOR=nano crontab -e

4. Input rule for the script to be started automatically

> * * * * * sh ~/sleep.sh

5. Re/start the current CronJobs:

> sudo touch /private/etc/crontab

P.S. I haven't tested it, but I will gladly help if anything additional is needed.