# Unlocking and locking mac screen via ssh

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, remote-control

Is there a way to unlock and lock screen from command line, via ssh? I know `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend` command, but it doesn't seem to work via ssh. The perfect solution would be a command, that I could type logged via ssh and it would unlock the screen or lock it back again, so I don't need to tell anybody my password, if he wants to use it. Is there any builtin tool, that would provide such functionality?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/159440/221083) (I'm using this method, and it works flawlessly).

Answer (score 9):

There are many ways to lock and unlock your Mac via SSH. The easiest and probably the fastest way is to use `osascript` (applescript).

### Locking Mac

To do this, log in via ssh and type in

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to sleep'
```

You can switch Finder for System Events, but that means more characters to type.

### Unlocking Mac

To wake your Mac is a little harder.

There are two ways to do this.

You can use `osascript` again.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 123'
```

This tells it to keystroke the left arrow key which should wake your Mac up from sleep.

You can also use the `pmset` command.

```
pmset schedule wake "mm/dd/yyyy 00:00:00"
```

Use a date and time that has already passed.

Of course you will need to keystroke your password via Applescript, e.g.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "password"'
```

An alternative to this could be the Remote Wake Up app for Mac, but I am not sure if you can put a password in.

Comment: I know, about the ability to make osx sleep remotely. I have been looking for something, that will just lock the screen, not put the computer to sleep. Something like win + L on windows, but via ssh. Also, I cant get to work this unlocking script.

Comment: @fulaphex `pmset displaysleepnow` seems to work for me: it will put the display to sleep immediately, and because in preferences/security&privacy/general I have "require password immediately after sleep or screen saver begins", it will also lock the station.

Comment: Shouldn‘t the Mac already be running/woken up to allow osascript to run?

Answer (score 2):

I use this for locking the screen (works on Big Sur):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "q" using {control down, command down}
end tell'
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

`sudo -S pmset schedule wake "$(date -j -v +2S +'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')"`

Wakes your Mac up in 2 seconds from now. (Interestingly enough, 1 second doesn't work.)

Good luck (to way over in 2016 )!