# Lock macOS with a password from bash

Tags: macos, command-line, security, password, screen-lock

Is there a way to lock macOS so that waking it up requires the user’s password? (Even If normally the password won’t be requested if it is waked up in, say, 1 hour)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock Screen Command One-Liner](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80058/lock-screen-command-one-liner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on most versions

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin

"/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession" -suspend

sleep 5

pmset sleepnow

osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to sleep'

exit 0
```

The `-suspend` line will switch to the login screen (which takes a few seconds, hence the `sleep 5` before the next command).

The `pmset` line will sleep the display.

The `osascript` line will sleep the computer.

Only the `-suspend` line is necessary to require the password, so you can choose to include the other lines, or not, as you wish.